# Android Java class casting

Tags: java, android, casting, downcast

I am wondering if someone could explain something about a class cast for me.

I am playing around with Android and I have a subclass of Application named ExApp.

I want to call a method of ExApp from one of my activities, so I do:

```
ExApp ex = ((ExApp)getapplication());
```

What I don't understand is why I need a double set of parentheses?  Why can't I just:

```
ExApp ex = (ExApp)getApplication();
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can. The two statements are exactly the same.

Where you'd see a difference is if you were calling a method on the result, e.g.

```
(ExApp) getApplication().foo();
```

is different to:

```
((ExApp) getApplication()).foo();
```

In the first case, it's the result of `foo()` which is cast to `ExApp`; in the second, it's the result of `ExApp`, and the overall expression is the return type of `foo()`.